# Dynamically create a user from ldap info in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ldap

I want to create a user dynamically immediately after an ldap search.

In the applications the user can search an ldap for an id and it returns an id and name if the person exists in ldap.

What I want to implement is when the id is displayed (post-search) the current user should have the option to create a new local user using the id and name that was returned from ldap.

Here is my view:

```
    <% if @users_ldap %>
        <%= @users_ldap.second.first %> # name
        <%= @users_ldap.first.first %> # id
# button to save info as local user here
```

Do I redirect to the create method in the user controller here? Is there a way to do this without leaving the current page? (If I want to be able to add many at once without refreshing)

Update:

Added a line:

```
 <% link_to 'Add', User.create({:id => @users_ldap.second.first, :name => @users_ldap.first.first,  :group_ids => ["#{params[:id]}"] }) %>
```

which adds a user as soon as the search is conducted. I would still like to make it dynamic (so on button click do this line)

Answer (score 0):

If you're not doing this asynchronously, then yes, the button should link to the `users#create` action.

Creating a user in rails sort of takes two actions, a `new` action to create a new, blank user instance and a `create` action to actually create the user based on your `user_params` hash. The button should link to this `create` action. You can edit where the form takes you by altering `form_tag`'s optional `:controller` and `:action` attributes.

```
form_tag(controller: "users", action: "create")
...
```

So long as you have a route that links to `users#create`, the action will be triggered. Inside this action you should call the `User` model and create a new User record.